# JSON object from ajax response

Tags: javascript, json

From JSON string below
`{cols:[{"id":"t","label":"Title","type":"string"},{"id":"l","label":"Avg ","type":"string"},{"id":"lb","label":"High","type":"string"},{"id":"lo","label":"Low","type":"string"}],rows:[{"c":[{"v":"Change navigation"},{"v":5.6666666666667},{"v":"10"},{"v":"1"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Executive leadership"},{"v":6.0666666666667},{"v":"7"},{"v":"3"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Business ownership"},{"v":5.8095238095238},{"v":"10"},{"v":"2"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Change enablement"},{"v":6.4285714285714},{"v":"9"},{"v":"5"}]}]}`

How do i get something like,

`['Change navigation=6.5333333333333','Executive leadership=6.0666666666667',
  'Business ownership=5.8095238095238','Change enablement=6.4285714285714']`

using Javascript

I got a JSON object as a response from AJAX.Now trying to draw an image chart with it.I applied JSON.stringify to convert the object.But dont know how to convert to a format which charts understand

Comment: so you want to create an array from json? or turn a json string into another string?

Comment: If you've already got a JSON object then you don't need to stringify it first - you won't be able to address the properties of it when it's a string...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `json` is your JSON object, you could use the below code:

```
var arr = [],
    i = 0;

for (; i < json.rows.length; i++) {
    arr.push(json.rows[i].c[0].v + '=' + json.rows[i].c[1].v);
}

console.log(arr);  // -> ["Change navigation=5.6666666666667", "Executive leadership=6.0666666666667", "Business ownership=5.8095238095238", "Change enablement=6.4285714285714"]
```

Here's a [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/teBF8/).

Comment: This is very useful.But i just realised there are scenarios where i get multiple JSON objects from AJAX called PHP file.so is there any way i can draw tables there in this AJAX called PHP file,rather than manipulating AJAX response?

Comment: also for the above code i get a response ["=6","=5.6666666666667","=7","=6.6666666666667","=5"]

Comment: You must be getting JSON that's formatted differently. Not sure I understand your new problem enough to help.

Comment: Yeah response was actually correct.it was having empty value in DB.well new problem is that.may be i will explain scenario well.i display a chart landing on page based on php scripts.then when i select one value from drop down,i make a ajax call.and another php script is triggered which should return 2 json objects(which enables to draw 2 different chart)

Comment: first thing is that when i cant return two json objects :(.second thing is that even if do that how will i manipulate them

Comment: Can you please tell me how to get a multidimensional array in javascript like below.[['Change navigation',6.5333333333333],['Executive leadership',6.0666666666667],['Business ownership',5.8095238095238],['Change enablement',6.4285714285714]]

Comment: Change the loop's content to this: `arr.push([json.rows[i].c[0].v, json.rows[i].c[1].v]);`

Answer (score 0):

Paste your JSON string into the magical JSONLint and you'll see that your JSON is not valid. JavaScript will try and get the valid parts, and that's why you don't get the full object.

http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: I think that it will still be parsable. People omit strings for their object literal keys all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Create a result array. Get the `rows` property of the parsed object, then loop through that array and, for each entry, push the appropriate string (`entry.c[0].v+" "+entry.c[1].v`) onto the result array. Done.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you'll have to loop through each row, and build a new set of objects in the format the chard control expects, then load that into the chart control.

Comment: or is it possible to draw the charts from the ajax called php file.In that case ,can avoid manipulating object

Comment: Check with the control whether that is supported; I don't even know what chart control it is to advise.